# Get individual folder permissions Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have been asked to write a script which will take in a destination and then output the folders and subfolders with their respective permissions.

I have got what I thought was a working script but have been told that they want the actual permission types. Can this actually be done using `Get-ACL`? Could anyone point me in the right direction for this I have no idea where to start with this and don't have all that much experience with using `Powershell`

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$info = ""
$OutputString = ""
$step = 0
$File = "C:\Gower\FolderPermissions.txt"

function DisplayForm{
$OutputString = ""

#Some GUI Code here taken out for readability

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{

    $baseFolder = $textBox.Text
    $folderTest = Test-Path $baseFolder
    if($folderTest -eq "True"){
        "$baseFolder `r`n" | Out-File $File -Append
        Extract-Permissions($baseFolder)
        "`r`n`r`n" | Out-File $File -Append
        #OutputList
        $info = "SAVED TO $File"
        "Process complete `r`nFile Located at: $file"
        DisplayForm
    }else{
        $info = "$baseFolder not found"
        DisplayForm
    }
}
}

function outputList{
    $OutputString
}



function Extract-Permissions($baseFolder) {
    $folders = Get-ChildItem $baseFolder | Where-Object { $_.PSisContainer }
    $baseACL = (Get-Acl $baseFolder).Access | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentityReference 

"$baseFolder : $baseACL" | Out-File $File -Append

if($folders.Count -ne 0){
    foreach($folder in $folders) {
        $folderACL = (Get-Acl $folder.FullName).Access | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentityReference
        $childFolders = Get-ChildItem $folder.FullName | Where-Object { $_.PSisContainer }

        "$($folder.FullName) : $folderACL" | Out-File $File -Append

        if($childFolders.Count -gt 0){
            foreach($childFolder in $childFolders) {
                $childACL = (Get-Acl $childFolder.FullName).Access | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentityReference
                if(Compare-Object $childACL $folderACL) {
                    Extract-Permissions $childFolder.FullName
                } else {
                    "$($childFolder.FullName) : $childACL" | Out-File $File -Append
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

DisplayForm
```

This code will give me a list that then looks something like this:

```
C:\temp : BUILTIN\Administrators BUILTIN\Administrators NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM BUILTIN\Users NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
C:\temp\du : BUILTIN\Administrators BUILTIN\Administrators NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM BUILTIN\Users NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
C:\temp\Gower : BUILTIN\Administrators BUILTIN\Administrators NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM BUILTIN\Users NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
C:\temp\penout : BUILTIN\Administrators BUILTIN\Administrators NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM BUILTIN\Users NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
C:\temp\Projects : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM DOMAIN\Domain Users DOMAIN\TestAdmin
C:\temp\Projects\A000 - Test0 : DOMAIN\Domain Users NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM DOMAIN\TestAdmin
C:\temp\Projects\A122 - Test12 : DOMAIN\Domain Users NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM DOMAIN\TestAdmin
C:\temp\Projects\A212 - TestA13 : DOMAIN\Domain Users NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM DOMAIN\TestAdmin
C:\temp\Projects\Template : DOMAIN\sam DOMAIN\Domain Users NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM DOMAIN\TestAdmin
```

Comment: But why reinvent the wheel when SysInternals has a program to do that: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/accessenum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Read, write and execute types from the object `(Get-Acl $baseFolder).Access` they are listed as `FileSystemRights`. The following function will exstract the `FileSystemRights` data and add it along side the permission name eg. `BUILTIN\Administrators-FullAccess`.

```
function Extract-Permissions($baseFolder) {
    $baseACLAccess = (Get-Acl $baseFolder).Access
    $folders = Get-ChildItem $baseFolder | Where-Object { $_.PSisContainer }
    $baseACL = $baseACLAccess | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentityReference 

    # Sort out output
    $BaseOutperms = ""
    $baseACLAccess | Foreach {$BaseOutperms += " "+$_.IdentityReference+"-"+$_.FileSystemRights }
    "$baseFolder : $BaseOutperms" | Out-File $File -Append

    if($folders.Count -ne 0){
        foreach($folder in $folders) {
            $ACLAccess = (Get-ACL $folder.FullName).Access
            $folderACL = $ACLAccess | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentityReference
            $childFolders = Get-ChildItem $folder.FullName | Where-Object { $_.PSisContainer }

            # Sort out output 
            $outperms = ""
            $ACLAccess | Foreach {$outperms += " "+$_.IdentityReference+"-"+$_.FileSystemRights }
            "$($folder.FullName) : $outperms" | Out-File $File -Append

            if($childFolders.Count -gt 0){
                foreach($childFolder in $childFolders) {
                    $childACLAccess = (Get-Acl $childFolder.FullName).Access
                    $childACL = $childACLAccess | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentityReference
                    if(Compare-Object $childACL $folderACL) {
                        Extract-Permissions $childFolder.FullName
                    } else {
                        # Sort out output 
                        $ChildOutperms = ""
                        $childACLAccess | Foreach {$ChildOutperms += " "+$_.IdentityReference+"-"+$_.FileSystemRights }
                        "$($childFolder.FullName) : $ChildOutperms" | Out-File $File -Append
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```